# Python Pandas Dataframe not filtering all the valid records

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV File as follows:

```
source,rule_expression,tag,tag_type
yarn_obj,table_dir like '%experiments%',Development,Engineering
Yarn,QueueName like 'Ft%',HR,test
Yarn​,QueueName like 'Fin%'​,Finance​,Subject Area​
Yarn​,QueueName like 'HR%'​,HR​,Subject Area​
Yarn​,QueueName like '%ETL%'​,ETL​,Worktype​
Yarn​,QueueName like '%DS%'​,Data Science​,Worktype​
Yarn​,Priority <> High and ExecutionTime > 3600​,Long running low value​,TimeValue​
Yarn​,Priority = High and ExecutionTime < 100​,Short running High value​,TimeValue​
HDFS​,Path like /datalake/Telco​,Telecom​,Subject Area​
Hive​,Table like manu%​,Manufacturing​,Subject Area​
```

And I am trying to read using pandas (need to use Pandas only, project reuirement).The issue I am facing is that Filter equality operator is not working as expected.

The data in CSV file was copied from Microsoft PPT and I want to filter "Yarn". The Pandas filter is able to filter only one record while there are 7 records.
The Python code is :

```
import pandas as pd

ruleDf = pd.read_csv("ScalarExpressions.csv", header="infer", encoding="utf-8")
print(ruleDf.info())
tes = ruleDf["source"].astype(str) == "Yarn"
print(tes)
print("__________")
yarnRules = ruleDf[tes]
print(yarnRules.head())
print("__________")
print(ruleDf["source"].head())
```

And the output is

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9       
Data columns (total 4 columns):      
source             10 non-null object
rule_expression    10 non-null object
tag                10 non-null object
tag_type           10 non-null object
dtypes: object(4)
memory usage: 448.0+ bytes
None
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: source, dtype: bool
__________
  source       rule_expression tag tag_type
1   Yarn  QueueName like 'Ft%'  HR     test
__________
0    yarn_obj
1        Yarn
2       Yarn​
3       Yarn​
4       Yarn​
Name: source, dtype: object
```

Any help or pointers will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have a hidden character after the word 'Yarn' in some of the rows.

To make the equality condition work, run the following:

```
ruleDf.source.str.strip().str.strip("\u200b") == "Yarn"
```

The first strip removes 'regular' whitespace. The second one removes the special character 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B).

The result is:

```
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8    False
9    False
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that indeed is the case, is there any way to remove these hidden characters in Pandas while loading the dataset instead of finding specific ones as is in your case. Also, I am accepting your answer as it solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I copy pasted the data as-is from your sample input file, and looks like you have additional unicode characters:

```
ls = set(ruleDf['source'])
```

Returns:

```
{'Hive\u200b', 'Yarn', 'yarn_obj', 'HDFS\u200b', 'Yarn\u200b'}
```

Can you check and verify this?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that indeed is the case, is there any way to remove these hidden characters in Pandas while loading the dateset